# Changing class name without loosing changes in the class

Tags: jhipster

guys can anyone help me i have a weird situation,
i have created an entity using j hipster and it created classes with that name and data base table as well, now my question is how can just change my class name.
i made some changes in the classes and i don't want to loose those changes

how could i change only the class name without loosing those changes

what i tried is [How to modify existing entity generated with jhipster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28216307/how-to-modify-existing-entity-generated-with-jhipster)

after this all code changes are gone, so with loosing code changes how can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an answer, but I faced the same issue lot of times, Usually I do this manually, trust me its not a lot of work.

**General Steps.**

**Step 1:** In the .jhipster folder, replace the classname.json file with your file new class name. Replace relationships if any.

**Step 2:** Change domain, repository, service(if exist), resource.

**Step 3:** Change the ui code.

This is a find/replace job just need to be more careful thats it.

**There is one tricky way though.**

**Step 1:** Create a new branch, if using git

**Step 2:** Create a new new_class_name.json file in the .jhipster project.

**Step 3:** Copy the json from old_class_name.json file in the new_class_name.json

**Step 4:** run the command "yo jhipster:entity new_class_name"

**Step 5:** This will create all the new files.

**Step 6:** Copy paste your changes in the new one.

**Step 7:** Delete old files.

I usually follow the first one. Trust me its not that difficult.

Comment: Thanks, will give it a shot.

Comment: How did it go Rakesh?

Comment: i put my class name as it is, i changed my data base table name by making changes in the domain and liquibase file. thanks for your response.